# Use multiple IF condition to set variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I receive parameters to stored procedure:

```
          @BDOnly                       BIT
        , @CDOnly                       BIT
        , @PPOOnly                      BIT
        , @FBOMOnly                     BIT
```

Then depending of this variables I do an IF condition to set other variables like:

```
  DECLARE @IsBDChecked   VARCHAR(10)
        , @IsCDChecked   VARCHAR(10)
        , @IsPPOChecked  VARCHAR(10)
        , @IsFBOMChecked VARCHAR(10)

    IF(@BDOnly = 1)
    BEGIN
       SET @IsBDChecked = 'Test1'
    END
    IF(@CDOnly = 1)
    BEGIN
       SET @IsCDChecked = 'Test2'
    END
    IF(@PPOOnly = 1)
    BEGIN
       SET @IsPPOChecked = 'Test3'
    END
    IF(@FBOMOnly = 1)
    BEGIN
       SET @IsFBOMChecked = 'Test4'
    END
```

Is that the best way to do this? or can I do better?

Comment: Performance-wise? Any difference between this approach and any other approach is probably going to be negligible. Are there other ways you could do this that might make it more readable? Sure. You can remove the brackets, remove the begin/end, do all the assignments in one line (with case expressions instead of using if), do all the assignments at the point of declaring the variables (again with case expressions), etc... It really comes down to personal preference how you want to do that.

Comment: Define "better"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the logic all inside one statement:

```
SELECT @IsBDChecked = (CASE WHEN @IsBDChecked = 1 THEN 'Test1' END),
       @IsCDChecked = (CASE WHEN @IsCDChecked = 1 THEN 'Test2' END),
       @IsPPChecked = (CASE WHEN @IsPPOChecked = 1 THEN 'Test3' END),
       @IsFBOMChecked = (CASE WHEN @IsFBOMChecked = 1 THEN 'Test4' END)
```

Comment: Inside the `CASE` should be the `@<thing>Only` variables.